# Using fabric.js, how can I use color from color picker in gradient colorstops in my code

Tags: fabricjs, color-picker, linear-gradients

I am trying to use color from color picker in my code

```
rec.setGradient('fill', {
          type: 'linear',
          x1: -rec.width / 2,
          y1: 0,
          x2: rec.width / 2,
          y2: 0,
          colorStops: {0 : '"'+$("#gradColor1").val()+'"' ,1 : '"'+$("#gradColor2").val()+'"'} ,
        });
```

But above code is not working and showing error in console.log as

```
TypeError: source is undefined
 return 'rgb(' + source[0] + ',' + source[1] + ',' + source[2] + ')';
```

jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/37hgdjda/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I am doing silly mistake.

corrected this line

```
colorStops: {0 : '"'+$("#gradColor1").val()+'"' ,1 : '"'+$("#gradColor2").val()+'"'} ,
```

to

```
colorStops: {0 : $("#gradColor1").val() + ' ,1 : '+$("#gradColor2").val()} ,
```

Corrected jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/37hgdjda/13/